# SQL Constraint Validate Unique Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a table and I need to restrict the data inserted, I already use a trigger but I was wondering if I could do the same task with a constraint.

The fields are:

```
Id
Date
Passport
...
Deleted
```

The constraint must allow **n** records while the **Deleted** field is **1**, but if the **Deleted** field is **0** there must be only one row with the same Date and Passport.

Should work for this steps:

1. Adding a row with Id=1, Date=2018-05-01, Passport=MPEUIE80, Deleted=0
2. Deleting the row with Id=1, so the field Deleted will be 1
3. Adding a row with Id=2, Date=2018-05-01, Passport=MPEUIE80, Deleted=0
4. Deleting the row with Id=2, so the field Deleted will be 1
5. Adding a row with Id=3, Date=2018-05-01, Passport=MPEUIE80, Deleted=0
6. Adding a row with Id=4, Date=2018-05-01, Passport=MPEUIE80, Deleted=0

Till the fifth step, everything works, but in the last step there must be an error, that is because I can't handle two rows with the same **Date**, same **Passport** and both with **Deleted**=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``The constraint must allow n records while the Deleted field is 1, but if the Deleted field is 0 there must be one Date and Passport`. Please explain this more clearly

Comment: Kind of smells like something is off in the design if you have one field representing multiple relationships. You can search for something like "Case statement with constraint", but I think a re-evaluation of the structure might be a better option.

Comment: You created a bounty but Gordon gave you an answer? What don't you like about the index?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller That answer didn't work.

Comment: Interesting question 8)

Comment: I think Gordon's hunch is right here; what is the compatibility setting of your database? Is it 90 or lower?

Comment: Could you add SQL Server @@Version and Edition?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use a filtered, unique index:

```
create table [t](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [passport] [char](8) NULL,
    [deleted] [int] NULL
)

create unique index unq_t_date_passport on t(date, passport)
    where deleted = 0;
```

EDIT:

If filtered indexes are not working on your version of SQL Server, then you might want to check the [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017).  It should be available whenever the compatibility is set to 100 or higher.  You can check your server version and compatibility level using:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;
```

There is another method that will work starting in SQL Server 2005, assuming the id is unique and non-negative.  It uses a computed column to do essentially the same thing as the filtered index:

```
alter table t
    add column deleted_id (case when deleted = 0 then -1 else id end) persisted;

create unique index unq_t_passport_date_deleted_id on t(passport, date, deleted_id);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: @WltrRpo Did you change `t` to the name of your table?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller yes I did, `create unique index unq_t_date_passport on [dbo].[Test] ([date], [passport]) where deleted = 0;`

Comment: @WltrRpo . . . Filtered indexes were introduced in SQL Server 2008 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax).  If they don't work for you, perhaps you have your compatibility level set to some earlier version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Shouldnt the 2005 solution be reversed? case when deleted = 1 then id else -1 end, otherwise the unique index is preventing multiple deleted rows - also should handle the date field to be complete

Comment: @KnarfaLingus .. . Thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer did it, I check and my database is Microsoft SQL Server 2005, so I check in other one (2014) and it's working. Thanks man.